# Binary tree benchmark results

Tags: c++, go, benchmarking

I stumbled upon [a website making benchmakrs](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/faster/go-gpp.html).
In this case Golang vs C++, binary trees.

The C++ solution does A LOT better than golang using allocation of a memory pool. 
I can get behind that but wondered how an implementation without that would fare. So I modified it to look more like the Golang-Code and removed concurrency for both.

In this example and on my machine the golang code runs in around 24 seconds.
The C++ code takes an average of 126 seconds. I did not expect this result at all. I expected C++ to still be faster or maybe be a bit slower but not by a factor of 5.

Did I make some huge mistake? Or do you know the reason for this? Code for both programs is below:

Built with:

> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -O2  -c D:\TMP\Test\main.cpp -o
>   obj\Release\main.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\Test.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    Node(uint64_t d);
    ~Node();
    int Check();
private:
    Node* l;
    Node* r;
};

Node::Node(uint64_t d){
    if (d > 0){
        l = new Node(d - 1);
        r = new Node(d - 1);
    } else {
        l = 0;
        r = 0;
    }
}

Node::~Node(){
    if(l){
        delete l;
        delete r;
    }
}

int Node::Check(){
    if (l) {
        return l->Check() + 1 + r->Check();
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t min_depth = 4;
    uint64_t max_depth = 21;
    for (uint64_t d = min_depth; d <= max_depth; d += 2) {
        uint64_t iterations = 1 << (max_depth - d + min_depth);
        uint64_t c = 0;
        for (uint64_t i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
            Node* a = new Node(d);
            c += a->Check();
            delete a; // I tried commenting this line but it made no big impact
        }
        cout << iterations << " trees of depth " << d << " check: " << c << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Golang:

> go version go1.7.1 windows/amd64

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

type Node struct {
    l *Node
    r *Node
}

func (n *Node) check() int {
    if n.l != nil {
        return n.l.check() + 1 + n.r.check()
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

func make(d uint) *Node {
    root := new(Node)
    if d > 0 {
        root.l = make(d-1)
        root.r = make(d-1)
    }
    return root
}

func main(){
    min_depth := uint(4)
    max_depth := uint(21)
    for d := min_depth; d <= max_depth; d += 2 {
        iterations := 1 << (max_depth - d + min_depth)
        c := 0
        for i := 1; i < iterations; i++ {
            a := make(d)
            c += a.check()
        }
        fmt.Println(iterations, " trees of depth ", d, " check: ", c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are using Go 1.7.1 instead of a more recent version (and not even the patched version of 1.7)? 1.11 was released about a month ago. https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html

Comment: What happens if you change the for loop in the C++ code to `Node a(d); c += a.Check();`?

Comment: None other than being lazy. The test was performed on my laptop, usually not coding much here - hence never updated.

Comment: or do not delete 'a' at all.

Comment: It shouldn't make a huge difference, but why did you let go make a 64-bit executable (more registers available, native `uint64_t`) while you used MinGW-32 to make a 32-bit executable (`uint64_t` takes multiple instructions, fewer registers and less-efficient stack-args calling conventions, but smaller pointers = smaller cache footprint)?  At least you enabled `-O2` optimization for MinGW.  `-O3 -march=native` might be interesting but probably won't make a difference.  `uint64_t` math is probably not a major bottleneck, but store/reload might be adding latency in a critical dependency chain.

Comment: Out of curiosity - on what CPU it was tested?

Answer (score 0):

It's something with your computer your ran on, because I'm getting the expected result where C++ is twice as fast as go.

C++

```
time cmake-build-debug/main
2097152 trees of depth 4 check: 65011681
524288 trees of depth 6 check: 66584449
131072 trees of depth 8 check: 66977281
32768 trees of depth 10 check: 67074049
8192 trees of depth 12 check: 67092481
2048 trees of depth 14 check: 67074049
512 trees of depth 16 check: 66977281
128 trees of depth 18 check: 66584449
32 trees of depth 20 check: 65011681
cmake-build-debug/main  21.09s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 21.113 total
```

GO

```
 jonny@skyhawk  ~/Projects/benchmark  time ./main            ✔  2604  02:34:29 
2097152  trees of depth  4  check:  65011681
524288  trees of depth  6  check:  66584449
131072  trees of depth  8  check:  66977281
32768  trees of depth  10  check:  67074049
8192  trees of depth  12  check:  67092481
2048  trees of depth  14  check:  67074049
512  trees of depth  16  check:  66977281
128  trees of depth  18  check:  66584449
32  trees of depth  20  check:  65011681
./main  48.72s user 0.52s system 197% cpu 24.905 total
```

I built the C++ main.cpp with CLion's mose basic / default settings (this CMakeLists.txt that will build a `main.cpp`)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(test_build)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(BUILD_1 main)
set(SOURCE_FILES_1 main.cpp)
add_executable(${BUILD_1} ${SOURCE_FILES_1})
```

Comment: Are you timing a debug build with C++?  Or was `cmake-build-debug/main` actually built with `-O3`?  Also note that your Go benchmark kept 2 CPU cores busy for the whole run time.  That seems surprising.

Comment: @PeterCordes it was a debug build, but once I saw it was exceptionally faster I didn't bother to optimize further. I just wanted to verify it was possible

Comment: Timing debug builds is meaningless.  We have no idea how much faster a normal build of either the C++ or the Go versions would be.